# Why hoc1 grammar has the following rules

Tags: unix, grammar, yacc, context-free-grammar, computation-theory

I was going through hoc program written in  The Unix Programming Environment. Came across the grammar as

```
list:     /* nothing */
        | list '\n'
        | list expr '\n'    { printf("\t%.8g\n", $2); }
        ;
```

What is the need of

```
| list '\n'
```

Looks like it will work even if we dont give that part of grammar! Then what is the importance of that part?

Printf is given with %.8g. What does that mean?

What to do if I need to give a prompt symbol? Just like $ in shell ?

Answer (score 1):

Three completely unrelated questions here

1. The rule `list: list '\n'` allows it to accept (and ignore) blank lines in the input.  Without it, any blank line would cause a syntax error.
2. The format specifier `%.8g` mean print a `double` argument with 8 digits of precision, using either normal or scientific notation, depending on what the exponent is.
3. If you want to print a prompt symbol, the easiest way is to do it in the lexer -- each time your `yylex` function reads a newline, it should print the prompt for the next line before returning the newline to the parser.  If you're using flex, this could be a rule like:

   ```
   \n    { if (interactive) {
             printf("$ ");
             fflush(stdout); }
           return '\n'; }
   ```

   you might want to check if your input is coming from a terminal or file and set the global `interactive` flag appropriately.